# LibGDX - is this possible to detect a moment when the screen becomes visible on user's device?

Tags: android, libgdx

I'm facing a huge problem with LibGDX screens.
As we know, `Screen` interface has some methods and one of these methods is `show()`. I thought that this method is called when the screen becomes 'visible' for the user - but it's not, it's called earlier (but after the constructor).

**My question is:**

Is this possible to detect the moment when the screen becomes fully visible?

Comment: resume().      ---------

Comment: isn't resume() called also on resume? If so, is it wise to make conditions like

public void resume(){
if(firstRun){
firstRun = !firstrun;
// do job
}
}

?

Comment: What problem do you actually have? Maybe it can be solved in another way.

Comment: I need to start loading assets/files when this moment comes. I solved it in 'render()'. Hacky, but there's no other way to make it in this exact moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "becomes fully visible" you mean when you should begin drawing something. Then I would guess its the first call to render(). render() is called after the constructor, show() and resize(). So the first call to render() would be the moment you make something visible on the screen.

But this does not stop you from drawing on the screen before you call render() or loading assets inside render().

So if you mean "when is the Screen done initializing/loading" then only you can decide that with your code.

Answer (score 0):

As per my observation, the call sequence of screen interface is:

```
1.public void show() {}
2.public void resize(int width, int height) {}
3.public void render(float delta){}
```

`pause()` and `resume()` called when you minimise or maximise your application.

in `resize()` method which called just before render method where you can write your code to do something just before `render()`.